# Scala program cannot find JDBC driver for Sql Server

Tags: scala, jdbc

My classpath begins:

```
C:\Tools\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\JDBC-Sql\sqljdbc_40\enu\sqljdbc.jar;
```

My test program is:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection

object TestJDBCSqlConnect {

def main(args: Array[String]) {     
 val driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

 try {
  // make the connection
  Class.forName(driver)

} catch {
  case e => e.printStackTrace
}

}
```

and when I run it via

```
scala -cp . TestJDBCSqlConnect
```

scala returns:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Is there some naming convention I am violating?

I am on JRE Version 8.

Comment: if you say `-cp .` then your classpath does *not* in fact, start with `C:\...\sqljdbc.jar`

Comment: I did not occur to me that I was overwriting the classpath. THANKS. That solves the problem.